# Is there any way to determine if a Google Drive file is shared to a certain group?

Tags: google-drive-api

So, is it possible to determine whether a file is shared to a certain group by use of Google Drive API (Google Documents API is out of the question, it will be deprecated during next year)? Listing permissions by use of [Google Drive API: List Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list) gives a list, in which all permissions related to groups have the email `null`. Another (extremely ugly) way I tried was to try and share the file with the group I want to check, to see if I would get an exception, but no. It happily reshares it. There must be someone else who has the need to check this except me!

Thanks

EDIT: The calls to the Google Drive API are done using the admin user, who owns the files.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you're not the only who needs this.

The Documents List API is a way to get the Group e-mail addresses: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_the_acl_for_a_document_file_or_collection

But you should use [getIdForEmail](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail). It might help you achieve what you're trying to do.